# Ruby on Rails querying over dateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I need to rewrite some DB query so my Rails app can run on Heroku. In one query I need to fetch all entries which are not older then one day. I tried it like this=>

```
Sendnotifications.where(:actionID => actionID.to_s,
:time =>  ['? >= time => ?', DateTime.now,DateTime.now-1]).all.count
```

But this does not work, I guess because of a wrong syntax. So the question is how can I solve this query problem?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sendnotifications.where(actionID: actionID.to_s)
  .where("time between ? and ?", DateTime.now, DateTime.now-1)
  .count
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to specify two boundaries, one will be more than enough (this way the code will look cleaner):

```
Sendnotifications.where('time > ?', DateTime.now - 1) #chain all your other methods
```